# Is there an equivalent to the Google Closure Compiler for Python?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, compression

I'm wondering if there is something that will scan through your code and remove any unnecessary functions.

Maybe the Python compiler already does this when it makes .pyc?  It'd be nice if there was something that did this at the .py level too.

Comment: No, it doesn't do that, because how would it know what would be called if the file was imported, or interpreted interactively, etc?

Comment: Why? The main (not to say *only*) reason to minify JS is saving bandwidth. But since Python code is relatively rarely sent over the network compared to Javascript which exists on most popular web pages en masse.

Comment: @delnan - I can sympathize with the OP: sometimes you inherit code that has been poorly mantained and has lot of obsolete classes and functions in it... Just cleaning it up makes it much more readable! :)

Comment: @mac: But that's not what the Closure compiler is for. It optimizes and minifies, removing unused code is just a side effect and the readability increase is instantly shadowed by (just *one* example) variables becoming one-letter abominations.

Comment: @delnan - I got you already at your first comment, don't worry! ;) I was rather suggesting that maybe the comparison was just for added clarity and did not implied the goal of the cleanup being the same. :)

Comment: Here's the use case: suppose I write a big library of Python code, then let someone else write something against my library.  Then I want to be able to provide a "all you need to include" file dynamically generated from the library plus their code.  The person might not necessarily be an experienced programmer, but they'd understand simple Python.

Comment: @Jeff - What you want to do seems very un-pythonic. Your library should be organised in such a way that the programmer/user it (experienced or not) should be able to import only what needed. Example: you write an AI for solving puzzles, and you provide classes to solve both mazes/spacial problems and word puzzles. The programmer should be able to do `from puzzleai import spacial` or `from puzzleai import wordy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's not such a software, because it would be extremely difficult to introspectively understand all the possible branches the code could execute based on different inputs (if you consider [metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), things would become even more complicated).

What you can do is to extrapolate how much / which code has (not) been executed during a test-run, and then evaluate yourself if such code can be safely removed. What you want to look for is some sort of **[code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)** utility.

In python two well known ones are [figleaf](http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/figleaf/doc/) and [coverage](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage).

**EDIT:** another approach could be that of using a profiler (and probably more specifically a call graph like [this one](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/)) to check that all your functions and classes are appearing in the graph itself (and then manually checking if those not appearing...)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for [PyLint](http://www.logilab.org/857).